# How to show different mesurement units according to the user locale in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, units-of-measurement, flutter-intl

I have to display a Value in both imperial and metric systems for example `1000 Liter` could be displayed as `1000 Gallons or 1000 Gl for shorl`  if the user is in the USA. or

- `500 ml` vs `500 Oz`
- `100 Miles` vs `100 Km`
  I have the locale of the user. but as far I know dart's Intl library support only date and language translations (maybe money too). How do I do this for distance and volume etc... any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure it out?